# Pentagon Midpoints intersection

Tags: geometry

Given a pentagon ABCDE such that the lines through the vertices A, B, C,D
and the midpoints A1, B1, C1, D1 of the sides CD, DE, EA, AB intersect each
other at the point P. Prove that the line through the points E and E1 (the
midpoint of the side BC) will also pass through the point P.

---

Comment: what have you triedso far? have you at least made a drawing to make it more visual?

Comment: No comment to @allizdog, 15 hours later ? At Maths Stack Exchange we like exchange. We don't encourage a "take and carry" approach...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is a simple algebraic approach. The identity $(*2)$ below implies
the sum of the signed area of the triangles
$PAA_1$, $PBB_1$, $PCC_1$, $PDD_1$ and $PEE_1$ is $0$. I wonder whether
this is an geometric argument to justify this so that we can get rid of the use of algebra completely.

---

**An algebraic approach**

WOLOG, choose $P$ to be the origin.

Embed the $\mathbb{R}^2$into $\mathbb{R}^3$ as the plane $z = 0$. i.e For each
$X = (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, we associate with it a point $\vec{X} = (x,y,0) \in \mathbb{R}^3$. In terms of their 3d counterpart, the condition $AA_1$ passing through $O$ is equivalent to
$$
\vec{A} \propto \vec{A_1} \quad\iff\quad \vec{A} \times \vec{A_1} = \vec{0} \quad\iff\quad \vec{A}\times\frac{\vec{C}+\vec{D}}{2} = \vec{0}
$$
Apply similar arguments to $BB_1$, $CC_1$ and $DD_1$, we have

$$
\color{red}{\vec{A}\times(\vec{C}+\vec{D})} =
\color{green}{\vec{B}\times(\vec{D}+\vec{E})} = 
\color{blue}{\vec{C}\times(\vec{E}+\vec{A})} =
\color{magenta}{\vec{D}\times(\vec{A}+\vec{B})} = \vec{0}\tag{*1}
$$

Notice for any $5$ vectors $\vec{A},\vec{B},\vec{C},\vec{D},\vec{E} \in \mathbb{R}^3$, independent whether they come $\mathbb{R}^2$ or not, we have
$$
\color{red}{\vec{A}\times(\vec{C}+\vec{D})} +
\color{green}{\vec{B}\times(\vec{D}+\vec{E})} + 
\color{blue}{\vec{C}\times(\vec{E}+\vec{A})} +
\color{magenta}{\vec{D}\times(\vec{A}+\vec{B})} +
\vec{E}\times(\vec{B}+\vec{C}) = \vec{0}
\tag{*2}
$$

Substitute $(*1)$ into $(*2)$, we get $\vec{E} \times (\vec{B} + \vec{C}) = \vec{0}$, This is precisely the condition that $EE_1$ also passing through the origin $P$.